# Gutenberg build error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type SCSS

Tags: block-editor

I had a plugin up and running with a scss to css compiler. Suddenly after I moved a few files into a better structure I get this error while building the block:

```
ERROR in ./blocks/random-game/src/style.scss 8:1
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| 
>  .wp-block-random-game {
|   
| }
 @ ./blocks/random-game/src/index.js 15:0-22
```

I don't understand why this happens and where I have to add a loader. I started with the create block script and built the plugin from there. Everything else works:

```
[./blocks/random-game/src/edit.js] 1.45 KiB {index} [built]
[./blocks/random-game/src/index.js] 983 bytes {index} [built]
[./blocks/random-game/src/save.js] 487 bytes {index} [built]
[./blocks/random-game/src/style.scss] 277 bytes {index} [built] [failed] [1 error]
```

Any idea where I can add the loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran these commands again and everything started to work again:

```
npm update    
npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev
```